# How to add custom video property to WebRTC SDP?

Tags: webrtc, sdp, janus-gateway

Is there a way to add custom video property to SDP? We would like to inform that transmitted video should be cropped to fit the remote screen.

As we are using Janus videoroom plugin also this information must be preserved after passing it.

Comment: You can, but to my knowledge, only Chrome supports custom changes to the sdp. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924430/how-can-i-change-the-default-codec-used-in-webrtc/26932385#26932385 You may also need to change how the SDP information is handled in the Janus plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding Janus, it is not possible. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meetecho-janus/Hj1vnR7ZPiw.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible after [this article](https://webrtchacks.com/limit-webrtc-bandwidth-sdp/#comment-17734).

Comment: certain well-defined properties can be changed. This doesn't apply to things like how to crop things (thankfully)