# Webrtc custom codec and dynamically change its configuration

Tags: webrtc, webrtc-android

In my android project, I am using **org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006** prebuilt library.

Is there any way, to use custom audio codecs? Also, how can I dynamically change codec configuration during the stream without recreating the stream/connection?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924430/how-can-i-change-the-default-codec-used-in-webrtc?

Comment: They setup codec configuration before creation of the stream with createAnswer and createOffer callbacks. I need to do this during the call and not only once. I want to change codec configuration dynamically.